# hover doesn't appear to be working

Tags: jquery

This works:

```
$('form').on('click','input:submit[name="Delete"]',function() {
    debugger;
});
```

But this doesn't:

```
$('form').on('hover','input:submit[name="Delete"]',function() {
    debugger;
});
```

Version: 2.0.0b2

Comment: That pseudo event was removed in 1.9, use `mouseenter mouseleave` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this instead:

```
$(".selector").on(
{
    mouseenter: function() 
    {
        //stuff to do on mouseover
    },
    mouseleave: function()
    {
        //stuff to do on mouseleave
    }
});
```

Or this way:

```
$(document).on('mouseover', 'input:submit[name="Delete"]', function() {
    //do something
});
$(document).on('mouseout', 'input:submit[name="Delete"]', function() {
    //do something
});
```

http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#hover-pseudo-event

> As of 1.9, the event name string "hover" is no longer supported as a
>   synonym for "mouseenter mouseleave". This allows applications to
>   attach and trigger a custom "hover" event. Changing existing code is a
>   simple find/replace, and the "hover" pseudo-event is also supported in
>   the jQuery Migrate plugin to simplify migration

Comment: Will toggleClass work correctly if I do it this way?  What I do is toggle the class to "btn-danger".

Comment: You can use `.toggleClass()` on mouseover or mouseout callback-